# How to convert date/time in Unicode to hh:mm:ss format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, datetime, unicode, matlab-figure, unicode-string

The following are my questions.

1. I have a unicode time array with numbers like `1.4243e+09` of type double. How do I convert this to hh:mm:ss format, disregarding the date if it's also encoded in the unicode values?
2. How to use the the converted values to plot against a dataset corresponding to these above timestamps?

the function `unicode2native` only works for string type inputs, but my input is of `'double'` type.

Comment: See [`datestr()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) and the [`timeseries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/time-series-objects.html) data type

Comment: In R2014b+ you may want to look into [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html). More [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2015/02/12/introduction-to-the-new-matlab-data-types-for-dates-and-time/).